# How to leverage cache on static images only?

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, cache-control

I've read that one needs to add the below code to leverage caching for static images. However, the images on our website change frequently and are dynamic (using asp.net). There are static ones but how do I indicate to only cache those static images?

The below code seems to cache all images.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:::

Using another example, I would do like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/images/>
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Please see the answer here as an example:  http://serverfault.com/questions/564314/apache-expiresbytype-per-directory

Comment: @NicholasSmith I edited my question, means it would be like that?

Comment: Yes in that case those caching rules would only apply to files in the /var/www/images folder.  You would adjust it to point to whatever folder you serve your static images from.

Comment: @NicholasSmith What if I need to add this to multiple directories? I also have JS and CSS to cache. Do I create another <Directory> tag?

Comment: Have multiple copies of that, one for each directory you want to handle.  There are other ways as well, you should research writing apache configuration files.